# Running MySQL with user=root

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm setting up a lamp server on my android phone, and i didn't managed to get mysql working with the default settings. i had to change the user to root in the my.cnf.
So i'm curious about the dangers of running mysql under the root user.

Comment: when you write "root user" are you referring to the mysql admin account or the operation system user "root"?

Comment: The operation system root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running MySQL as root, means everything the server does is also done as root (obvious). Especially if you happen to make a mistake, this can cause problems:

- if you mis configure the mysql logfile to `/etc/passwd`, then that important file will probably be overwritten (a normal user cant do that).
- **root** usually as some amount of disk system reserved (per filesystem), thus you can easier make the partition full as root.
- code injection: if you have scripts running (for backup of the now root owned files) than you need higher privileges there, and again any mistake might have a bigger impact.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to login as a root user. However, use it to create new users with limited privileges on objects (tables, indexes, databases, etc) so that those users can't break anything other than what they're allowed to :)

Once the new users are created logout as root and login with those new users. I see you're using linux, so the idea of root user applies to MySQL in a similar way as in linux.

You can check the official documentation about this: [Adding users and granting privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html)